# neo4j get random path from known node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a big neo4j db with info about celebs, all of them have relations with many others, they are linked, dated, married to each other. So I need to get random path from one celeb with defined count of relations (5). I don't care who will be in this chain, the only condition I have I shouldn't have repeated celebs in chain.

To be more clear: I need to get "new" chain after each query, for example:

- I try to get chain started with Rita Ora
- She has relations with
  Drake, Jay Z and Justin Bieber
- Query takes random from these guys, for example Jay Z
- Then Query takes relations of Jay Z: Karrine
  Steffans, Rosario Dawson and Rita Ora
- Query can't take Rita Ora cuz
  she is already in chain, so it takes random from others two, for
  example Rosario Dawson
- ...
- And at the end we should have a chain Rita Ora - Jay Z - Rosario Dawson - other celeb - other celeb 2

Is that possible to do it by query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable in Cypher, but it's quite tricky. You mention that

> the only condition I have I shouldn't have repeated celebs in chain.

This condition could be captured by using *node-isomorphic pattern matching*, which requires all nodes in a path to be unique. Unfortunately, this is not yet supported in Cypher. It is [proposed as part of the openCypher project](https://github.com/opencypher/openCypher/issues/174), but is still work-in-progress. Currently, Cypher only supports [relationship uniqueness](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/introduction/uniqueness/), which is not enough for this use case as there are multiple relationship types (e.g. A is married to B, but B also collaborated with A, so we already have a duplicate with only two nodes).

**APOC solution.** If you can use the APOC library, take a look at the [path expander](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_uniqueness), which supports various uniqueness constraints, including `NODE_GLOBAL`.

**Plain Cypher solution.** To work around this limitation, you can capture the node uniqueness constraint with a filtering operation:

```
MATCH p = (c1:Celebrity {name: 'Rita Ora'})-[*5]-(c2:Celebrity)
UNWIND nodes(p) AS node
WITH p, count(DISTINCT node) AS countNodes
WHERE countNodes = 5
RETURN p
LIMIT 1
```

Performance-wise this should be okay as long as you limit its results because the query engine will basically keep enumerating new paths until one of them passes the filtering test.

The goal of the `UNWIND nodes(p) AS node WITH count(DISTINCT node) ...` construct is to remove duplicates from the list of nodes by first [UNWIND-ing](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/clauses/unwind/) it to separate rows, then [aggregating them to a unique collection using `DISTINCT`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect). We then check whether the list of unique nodes still has 5 elements - if so, the original list was also unique and we `RETURN` the results.

**Note.** Instead of `UNWIND` and `count(DISTINCT ...)`, getting unique elements from a list could be expressed in other ways:

(1) Using a [list comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension) and ranges:

```
WITH [1, 2, 2, 3, 2] AS l
RETURN [i IN range(0, length(l)-1) WHERE NOT l[i] IN l[0..i] | l[i]]
```

(2) Using [reduce](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reduce):

```
WITH [1, 2, 2, 3, 2] AS l
RETURN reduce(acc = [], i IN l | acc + CASE NOT i IN acc WHEN true THEN [i] ELSE [] END)
```

However, I believe both forms are less readable than the original one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the main goal of my task is a **random** chain of celebs from one know celeb, is that doable? By the way, I can use APOC, now I'm researching apoc.coll.randomItem(), but still have no idea how to use it in my case

Comment: I'd first run a simple query using APOC's path expander to see whether it returns paths deterministically. If they are random, that's great. If they are not, you have to introduce some randomness manually - Cypher also has a random() function.

Comment: I don't believe the paths are random, but once you have the possible paths from the path expander, all you have to do is collect them then use `apoc.coll.randomItem()` to grab a random path.